# Is there a way to find out which credentials were used if i get an "Access denied" message for images in an SSRS report?

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I do have a simple report that should contain images that are stored on a network share. In my database I only have the image paths.

Now for some reason that I am not able to find I get the message: 
"An error occurred retrieving the external resource 'file:////share/path/file.jpg' : Access to the path '\share\path\file.jpg' is denied."

As I do not use an unattended user account I have added the name of the mashine to the security settings of this path with full access for testing purposes. Unfortunatly it does not work, I also tried to use my credentials, because I thaught maybe it uses those, but unfortunatly I do have no luck.

For this reason I wanted to ask you if you know of a way to find out which credentials the server used to access the file, so that I can give the correct permissions.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to check if the SQL server user has the access to the network drive where image is stored.

Comment: HI Thanks for the suggestion. I added both: the computer that runs the sql server and the computer that runs the SSRS with read permission, but I still cannot see the image on the report.

Answer (score 0):

The image is probably being accessed either by the user accessing the report, or by the SSRS service account, or the application pool behind the web front end.

There is an execution history table (and views) in the `ReportServer` database. You can find out who is executing the reports and any errors messages encountered when executing them.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I ran the Query and in the column UserName is my own domain\username. The only problem with this is, that I do have access to the file, but in the logfile (under Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10_50.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles) it still says "Access to the path [...] is denied". Do you have any other idea?

Comment: That would leave me to believe that the reporting server, when accessing resources, is using either the reporting services service account credentials or the report server application pool identity. In our environment, we have a domain service account assigned to the SQL Server Reporting Services service that has access to report resources. I don't think we have touched application pool settings. Alternatively, you may also be able to launch the Reporting Services Configuration Manager, connect to your server, and specify an execution account.